# Creating a user-defined function with SQL::Statement::Functions in Perl creates a syntax error

Tags: sql, perl, function, user-defined

I am trying to work with UDFs, defined through SQL::Statement::Functions in Perl with a mySQL database in the backend. I am playing it by the book, as stated in [http://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Statement::Functions#User-Defined-Functions](http://metacpan.org/pod/SQL%3a%3aStatement%3a%3aFunctions#User-Defined-Functions), however, before I even leave square one, an error in the CREATE FUNCTION statement is rearing its ugly head.
Here's the code first ($dbh is a given and works fine, it is just part of a bigger construct of the framework I am working with, so I don't want to spam my question with all of it; if I replace `foo()` in the SELECT by 22, or by "_PK FROM locations", all is good and I get a 22 or a value corresponding to the query in Data::Dumper, so, the connection is ok):

```
use Data::Dumper;
use SQL::Statement::Functions;

sub foo {
    return 999;
}

#$dbh is defined elsewhere
$dbh->do("CREATE FUNCTION foo") or die "error creating function foo(); " . $dbh->errstr;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT foo(22)") or die "error preparing query: " . $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute or die "error executing query: " . $sth->errstr;

my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref();
print "ROW " . Dumper($row);
```

The error message reads as follows: `error creating function foo(); You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`, refering to the `$dbh->do("CREATE...")` line.

I have tried to dumb the CREATE FUNCTION part down as much as possible, but I also tried it with `...foo EXTERNAL` and `...foo EXTERNAL NAME foo` as suggested by the manual. Heck, I even created a package for the function, to no avail.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

I checked, and the user I am connected to the database with does have all privileges, including alter_routine_priv and create_routine_priv, if that is what SQL::Statement is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the module as it is intended. It's an extension to the SQL::Parser module that is used by DBDs to implement SQL syntax and functions. The documentation states:

> This module contains the built-in functions for SQL::Parser and
>   SQL::Statement. All of the functions are also available in any DBDs
>   that subclass those modules (e.g. DBD::CSV, DBD::DBM, DBD::File,
>   DBD::AnyData, DBD::Excel, etc.).

To me, that sounds like it has nothing to do with mysql. The DBD::mysql is used as a wrapper around a real mysql database. It just connects, forwards the queries, prepares them and so on. It does *not parse* them, however. That's what the database is doing, just like if you were to connect to an Oracle or MSSQL database. In those cases, the driver is like an API wrapper.

On the other hand, DBD::CSV and the others mentioned above are parsing the sql themselves. DBD::CSV opens a CSV file, understands the SQL and (very simply described) translates it into Perl code to look for stuff in the CSV data. The same goes for the others. They use SQL::Parser to make sense of the SQL. SQL::Statement::Functions seems to be the module that provides the equivalent Perl functions for the SQL.

> When using SQL::Statement/SQL::Parser directly to parse SQL ...

Comment: On the other hand, I unfortunately have no idea if what you are trying to do is possible. I'm certain it is not with this module, though. DBD::sqlite also has custom functions built it. Maybe that's an alternative.

Comment: It most certainly has nothing to do with mySQL, I just mentioned the mySQL database as an additional information since that question might have come up anyway at some point.
Just be sure that I refer to SQL::Statement::Functions, instead of Parse or just Statement. Functions is built exactly for the purpose I am using it for and no much else. But you are right in so far as the whole library is DBD-agnostic, at least as far as I understand the manual. Heck, the whole purpose of the thing is to integrate perl subs into SQL in order to abstract from SQL's own, often unwieldy function syntax.

Comment: However, your take on SQL::Statement::Functions is not correct, this library's purpose is, as I pointed out (constrained by comment length), to offer an interface for the definition of _user_defined_ functions, nothing to do with the equivalent Perl functions to existing SQL functions (which is how I understand your second-to-last sentence), so your SQL::Statement and ::Parser reference is a bit off. And what I am trying to accomplish is definitely possible, it is the sole raison d'être of this module and it is described thusly by its manual. Please check the perldoc I linked in my question.

Comment: damn, tried to edit my comment and was already late. Replace "nothing to do with" by "in addition to" in the previous comment;-)
And the "sole" in front of the "raison d'être".

Comment: I did check that. It's part of the SQL::Statement distribution, which is an DBMS. The [manual for that](http://p3rl.org/SQL::Statement), on the other hand, clearly explains what it does. The SQL::Statement::Functions docs say that it provides the implementation of the SQL functions for custom DBDs (like DBD::CSV). If you take a look at https://metacpan.org/requires/distribution/SQL-Statement you will see that it is not used by DBD::mysql. You could try to monkeypatch it in there, but since that DBD is not parsing the SQL, that will not work either I'm afraid. :-/

Comment: Now, that metacpan reference was really helpful, right on the money. Damn! And here I thought Functions did away with that pesky proprietary function writing in all the SQL dialects. Well, the world needs injustice, otherwise we wouldn't recognize justice if it hit us over the head. But you get the cookie;-) It just took your comment to make me see your point.
Unfortunately I need something that is DBD-agnostic. So, back to the drawing-board:-S

Comment: If you find it, please let me know. ;-)